# Resolving Forces With Vectors. Find the Resultant Force

Tags: vectors, classical-mechanics

In this system, a particle on a horizontal surface is acted on by two forces, $F_1$ and $F_2$. Find the $\hat i$ and $\hat j$ components of the resultant force, where $\hat j$ represents due north and $\hat i$ due east. $F_1 = 3\hat i + 2\hat j$, $F_2$ has a magnitude $5$ N and acts at a bearing of 60 degrees. I thought that I had to resolve $F_2$ into horizontal and vertical components $5\cos(60^\circ)$ and $5\sin(60^\circ)$ and then add these to the $\hat i$ and $\hat j$ parts of $F_1$, giving me $5.5\hat i$ and $6.33\hat j$ for the resultant force, but the mark scheme says that the answer is $7.33\hat i + 4.5\hat j$. I don't know how to get to these, and I don't think I've made any stupid mistakes, but if I have, please let me know.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: the angled $90^\circ-60^\circ =30^\circ$ should be used instead of $60^\circ$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible way of getting the answer you have in the key is considering that $F_{2}$ "acts at a bearing of 60 degrees" means that this angle is not formed with the positive direction of x-axis, but with the one of the y-axis. Equivalently, we can say that the direction of the applied force is not north of east relative to the coordinate system, but the *east of north*. Then, The horizontal component of $F_{2}$ is $5sin(60^\circ) = 5*1.73/2 = 4.33$, and the vertical one is $5cos(60^\circ) = 5*0.5 = 2.5$. Then, adding these components to the corresponding ones of $F_{1}$:
$$R = (3+4.33)\hat{i} + (2+2.5)\hat{j} = 7.33\hat{i} + 4.5\hat{j}$$

Because of this ambiguity, in this kind of problems, besides the angle, it is usually indicated the **direction** too (in our example, north of east vs. east of north), so the condition is not really accurate.